# Using return_url. The "?" added by Paypal is a problem for me

Tags: paypal, payment

In the usage of the return_url field, Paypal adds a "?" before the parameters it returns.
In my case, the "?" either deleted or replaced by a "/".

How to do please?

Thanks for your help !

**Example :**

return_url = "https://localhost:6000/api/utilisateur/validationpaiement"

Paypal return : https://localhost:6000/api/utilisateur/validationpaiement?12345

I would like to obtain :

https://localhost:6000/api/utilisateur/validationpaiement/12345

Answer (score 0):

return_url = return_url.Replace("?", "/")

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible I think. But most framework/language/router can handle this kind of scenario. What would you use to handle the request?
If you are not able to change the way your app deals with return urls (ie: closed app, enterprise environment, etc.), you can still "convert" the request with an intermediate script in the language of your choice:

- listen for `https://localhost:6000/api/utilisateur/validationpaiement?xxxx` urls
- then make a call to `https://localhost:6000/api/utilisateur/validationpaiement/xxxx` and forward whatever content you received

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. Finally, I understood that the source of the blocking was not the "?" because it works with Postman. Unfortunately, this does not work with the browser ... and I'm looking for why

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).